# can we automate silverlight screens using watir?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, firewatir

Can we automate silverlight screens using watir? On the home page of watir, it's written that watir can automate any web application no matter what platform it is built on. But I read that it doesn't support applets or microsoft silverlight. Please help me regarding this. If we can automate silverlight screens, then please tell how?

Answer (score 2):

No, watir can not automate anything inside browser plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Content inside plugins such as Flash and Silverlight is not really exposed inside the DOM and so is difficult to test with Watir.  However there are other tools you can use in combination with Watir such as [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)  (use Jruby in that case to run watir, cucumber etc and use them in combination with Sikuli which is java based)

Comment: If that helped to solve your challenge, please accept the answer

Comment: Can anyone please tell me that what is the difference between Watir, Watij, Watin except the language used to write the script?? and how efficient these tools are.. here efficient mean what level of automation. Can we purely depend on them

Comment: @sahil.aggarwal you should ask this as a question, not as a comment.